# SPWebApplication is null in Feature Reciever

Tags: development, feature-receiver

in this code variable _service is null. Any idea what's wrong? It was working before without any problems...

```
private SPWebApplication _service;
...
_service = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your feature is not web application scoped.

Comment: Oh yeah, right, is there possibility to get SPWebApplication without running on WebApplication Scope?

Comment: This is the also way how to get WebApp on Web scope...             

    var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    _service = web.Site.WebApplication;